# Need a hash function to create 32 bit value out of ipv6 16 Byte address and TCP 2 Byte port numbers

Tags: c++, c, networking, network-programming, ipv6

I want to create a hash value of 32 bit. I have 16 byte source and destination ipv6 addresses and 2 byte source and destination port numbers.

32 bit Output = (Src IP,Dst Ip,Src Port,Dest Port)

It would be better if the hash function distribute the entities well along the 32 bit space. I want to use the result as an index.

Resit

Comment: is high performance a requirement?

Comment: Why not use MD5 or SHA-1 and cut the unneeded bits off? Although, i must say, that would waste a lot of information. Or do you have any other requirements like speed or memory consumption?

Comment: @RedX - see ^^ _is high performance a requirement_  :)

Comment: Well yes high performance is important. This is going to be used in a network application. Simplicity is also important. I do not want it to be a complex algorithms/code. It does not have to have a perfect distribution.

Answer (score 5):

Another, may be useful references:

[General Purpose Hash Function Algorithms](http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/index.html)

[CityHash by Google](http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/)

Note that, it is very hard to make a no collision guaranteed hash function (no different input result in the same hash code). There are many solutions to this problem, most simple one is the open addressing.

[Open Addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing)

Comment: Thank you, General Purpose Hash Function Algorithms seems to be the way to go. I will experiment with their algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

32 bits for an index? How big is your table?!

Consider that most IPv6 addresses are going to be based on a hardware address. Take a look at [RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#page-20):

```
[EUI64] defines a method to create an IEEE EUI-64 identifier from an
IEEE 48-bit MAC identifier.  This is to insert two octets, with
hexadecimal values of 0xFF and 0xFE (see the Note at the end of
appendix), in the middle of the 48-bit MAC (between the company_id
and vendor-supplied id).  An example is the 48-bit IEEE MAC with
Global scope: 

|0              1|1              3|3              4|
|0              5|6              1|2              7|
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|cccccc0gcccccccc|ccccccccmmmmmmmm|mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm|
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

That being the case, try this quick and dirty hack that would work in most cases (assuming an even distribution of ports and MAC addresses):

- Take the lower 16 bits of the source IPv6 address. Shift it 16 bits to the left and OR it with the lower 16 bytes of the destination IP address
- Take the source port. Shift it to the left by 16 bits and OR it with the destination port
- XOR the result of the two above 32-bit values together

If the user is using manually assigned addresses, this hash function won't be very evenly distributed, but I think in most cases it'll be close. You could throw in (XOR) some bits from the upper part of the address if you want.

Comment: Well this was very helpful. I did not consider the creation procedure of ipv6 addresses. I do not use 32 bit index. Our algorithm is very simple, it calculates a 32 bit value, then we take module of the output by size of our buffer. I do not know how effective it is is , but it works . The problem is, i want to use same hash table for 128 and 32 bit input indexes.

Answer (score 1):

See [Eternally Confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx) for some general information on hash functions and several well-known algorithms; I'd probably go with FNV or Jenkins' One-at-a-time hash.

Answer (score 1):

[murmurhash](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/) is very fast and fairly well-respected, as far as I can tell.  It is not cryptographic strength, but it should be adequate for your purposes.